# Kendo UI Gridview Column Client Template not working

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid()
 ......
 ......
  .columns.Bound(c => c.Status).EditorTemplateName("_WorkStatusDropDown")
**.ClientTemplate("# if (1) { #" + "Open" + "# }  else if (2) { #" + "Closed" + "# } else {#" + "In Progress" + "# } #");**
```

c.Status is a nullable int?

If I comment out the [ClientTemplate], I see the correct int representation of the status value. However if I use the client template - It always shows "Open" as the status.

```
Status : 1 = Open, 2 = Closed, 3 = In Progress
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**VIEW**

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Student>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.StudentID);
            columns.Bound(c => c.StudentName);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Status).ClientTemplate("# if (Status == 1) { #" + "Open" + "# }  else if (Status == 2) { #" + "Closed" + "# } else {#" + "In Progress" + "# } #");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_Read", "Home"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Grid_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    students.Add(new Student() { Status = 1, StudentID = 1, StudentName = "a" });
    students.Add(new Student() { Status = 2, StudentID = 2, StudentName = "a" });
    students.Add(new Student() { Status = 3, StudentID = 3, StudentName = "c" });

    return Json(students.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if any concern.